# ArcGIS Server Security related justification

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, references, security, windows-server-2008

We just installed ArcGIS server(JAVA) and the network security has a few policy that requires us to provide justification on our setting.

Does anyone have any reference document for the following questions?

1. Why must "arcgismanager" have access to the network folder?

Basically they believe that noone should have access to the folder.

Where can I find the document that states arcgismanager is required to the folder for configuration of ArcGIS Server?

2. We have a batch job, and it requires ArcGISSOM, ArcGISSOC, ArcGISManager to have access to perform the batch job.

Basically is the same as the above, we need to provide document that it is absolutely necessary for those 3 roles to have their ACL.

Where can I find the documents?

3. Remove Excessive Permission from CATALINA_HOME - conf, webapps, bin, logs

Basically we set full control for all the above mention folder to all the 3 roles, they aren't happy with that and just want to bear minimum for the arcgis server(JAVA) to work.

Is there a set of mininum access right for those folders to the 3 roles?

4. 2.1.1 Upgrading of tomcat server in ArcGIS (ArcGIS JAVA). They want to know if it is possible to upgrade ArcGIS server internal tomcat servers -.-

Can you help me answer the above 4 questions with references to ArcGIS official documentation?